# spark-shell - failure to initialize terminal (Windows 10, official cmd.exe)

Tags: apache-spark, cmd, windows-10

I'm trying to run Spark on Windows 10 with hadoop on the official Microsoft terminal `cmd.exe`.

I don't have problem with Hadoop. The installation and stating is OK.

I'm using Java 8 x64 (jdk1.8.0_92)

When I start Spark with the command `spark-shell`, I got the Java error bellow :

`[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class scala.tools.fusesource_embedded.jansi.internal.Kernel32
        at scala.tools.fusesource_embedded.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.getConsoleMode(WindowsSupport.java:50)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.WindowsTerminal.getConsoleMode(WindowsTerminal.java:204)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.WindowsTerminal.init(WindowsTerminal.java:82)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:158)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.console.ConsoleReader.(ConsoleReader.java:229)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.console.ConsoleReader.(ConsoleReader.java:221)
        at scala.tools.jline_embedded.console.ConsoleReader.(ConsoleReader.java:209)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline_embedded.JLineConsoleReader.(JLineReader.scala:61)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline_embedded.InteractiveReader.(JLineReader.scala:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$instantiate$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:865)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$instantiate$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:862)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$mkReader$1(ILoop.scala:871)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ILoop.scala:875)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ILoop.scala:875)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$15.apply(ILoop.scala:875)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$15.apply(ILoop.scala:875)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1233)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1223)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.collect(Stream.scala:435)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.chooseReader(ILoop.scala:877)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$2.apply(ILoop.scala:916)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:916)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:911)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:911)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:911)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)`

Answer (score 0):

I get exactly the same stack trace when opening the scala console in Netbeans. If I type any scala expression below the stack trace, it works fine though.